# Assign Azure SQL Server full ownership permissions to new user

Tags: azure

How to transfer Azure SQL Server full ownership permissions to new user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this path should answer your question:

In the Azure portal --> Search for and select SQL server --> On the SQL Server page, select Active Directory admin --> In the Active Directory admin page, select Set admin --> In the Add admin page, search for a user, select the user or group --> At the top of the Active Directory admin page, select Save.

**More info you can find in below Microsoft docs:**

Configure and manage Azure AD authentication with Azure SQL

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell

**Authorize database access to SQL Database, SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage